# Solve screen tearing with nouveau (without switching to proprietary Nvidia driver)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, nouveau, tearing, nvidia-settings

I know similar questions have been asked and answered here, but my issue is different: I want to get rid of screen tearing staying with the `nouveau` Xorg driver, not with NVIDIA proprietary driver.

The reason is that my notebook (Asus G75VW) is peculiar in having only Nvidia GPU (no Intel GPU on board). As a result, when using dual monitor setup (with external monitor attached via display port), the GPU temperature quickly rises to 50 degrees even in idle state (no movies/games), and after that point the GPU fan speeds up, yielding that annoying noise... Well, that was back a while ago when I had MS Windows installed, so I used a single external monitor. Recently I switched to Ubuntu 18.04 and - heavens! - my notebook became much less noisy in dual-monitor setup, as the GPU temperature hardly reaches 43 degrees even when an HD movie is run on external monitor!

One problem though: screen tearing while playing videos. I found the solution at SE: in `nvidia-settings` turn on the option `Force composition pipeline`. For this to work, I obviously had to switch to proprietary Nvidia driver from the `nouveau` driver which was used by default. And - voila! - the temperature-an-noise problem is back again. By the way, simply switching to proprietary driver does not solve screen tearing; additionally enabling `force composition pipeline` removes screen tearing indeed. The GPU temperature becomes high even without enabling it.

So I would like to stick with the `nouveau` driver but to get rid of screen tearing. Thus far, I tried `compton` instead of the `xfce4` native window manager, both with `xrender` and `glx` backends, but that didn't solve screen-tearing issue.

[*Alternatively, since I don't play games, I might consider using Nvidia driver but tweak GPU to minimize its load and hence temperature. I investigated options available in `nvidia-settings` and found only few that I could change; they made no difference; could there be something I have missed, though?*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that worked for me was to switch to Wayland instead of X11. Wayland uses `nouveau`, and there is no screen-tearing when playing videos.